# take screenshot from layout and share via android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I use below code to take screen shot from my layout and share it via android intent but the captured screen shot in the selected app is not showing any thing.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

           shareBitmap(this,takeScreenshot());

}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    try{
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.lyt_main_report_activity);
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
public static void shareBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bitmap){

    //save to sd card
    try {

        File cachePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
        cachePath.mkdirs(); // don't forget to make the directory
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/image.png"); // overwrites this image every time
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        stream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        //start share activity
        File imagePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile); //FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.persianswitch.apmb.app.fileprovider", newFile);

        if (contentUri != null) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
           // shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, context. getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));

        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: does this line `shareBitmap(this,takeScreenshot());` not give you problems?

Comment: The problem is that the generated bitmap buffer is only cotaining 0

Comment: so you mean `rootView.getDrawingCache();` returns a successful bitmap?

Comment: returns a successfull bitmap but the bitmap's buffer only contains 0 value

Comment: last question do you have hardware acceleration is turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code this is tested code :

```
public static void takeScreenshot(Context context, View view) {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
        "/" + "test.png";

    View v = view.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream out = null;
    File imageFile = new File(path);

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        // choose JPEG format
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // manage exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // manage exception
    } finally {

        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {}

    }

    // onPauseVideo();
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
    share.setType("image/png");
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Drawing"), 111);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **DrawingCache()** deprecated above 28 so using **Canvas** will sort the issues for many. below answer can be used for share Screenshot including text without requesting for permissions.

To take the Screenshot

```
    private Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

To share the Screenshot

```
 private void shareContent(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            binding.getRoot().getContext().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title", "");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Currently a new version of KiKi app is available.");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    binding.getRoot().getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing happens it means your `Bitmap` is `null` kindly check that. or you could also fall on `View.buildDrawingCache();` which will draw the View to Bitmap and then call your `View.getDrawingCache();`

> also When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag. If you want to use a Bitmap for the view, even when hardware acceleration is enabled, see [setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) for information on how to enable software and hardware layers.

the quote was taken from the [documented page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Tipp:The checked answer works when your device has external storage. On the Samsung 6 for example, it doesnt. Therefore you need to work with fileprovider.

Just incase somebody fell into this trap like me. The problem is that you are putting the name of the image twice.

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/image.png");
```

and than again.

```
 File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
```

Change The seconed one to

```
File newFile = new File(imagePath);
```

Otherwise the contentUri give you the bitmap of your screenshot. I hope this helps someone. Took me 3 hours to figure it out :)